# jQuery AJAX POST request OK in Chrome, fails with 415 in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, xml, rest, http-headers

I am building an interface for a remote XML service.  Here is my $.ajax function:

```
this.sendInput = function () {
    jQ.ajax({'url': URL, 
             'type': 'POST', 
             'data': app._CONTENT, 
             'contentType': 'text/xml', 
             'dataType': 'XML', 
             'error': function (data) { app.processError(data); }, 
             'success': function(data){ app._OUTPUT = data; app.processOutput(); }});
};
```

When I send this request to the server with Chrome, I get a 200 response with the following headers:

```
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, \*/\*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:930
Content-Type:text/xml
Host:host.com
Origin:http://elsewares.org
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://blah.org
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
```

When I send the same request in Firefox 12, I get a 415 error with the following request headers:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He...    content-type
Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Host    host.com
Origin  http://host.org
Pragma  no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 FirePHP/0.7.1
x-insight   activate
```

I should note that the server is set to allow Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, so we can set the body of the POST request as XML.

Any ideas what the mismatch is here?  Firefox is a MUST for this to work in the setting where it's going to be used.

Here is the body of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <MELTSinput>
        <initialize>
            <SiO2>48.68</SiO2>
            <TiO2>1.01</TiO2>
            <Al2O3>17.64</Al2O3>
            <Fe2O3>0.89</Fe2O3>
            <Cr2O3>0.0425</Cr2O3>
            <FeO>7.59</FeO>
            <MnO>0.00</MnO>
            <MgO>9.10</MgO>
            <NiO>0.0</NiO>
            <CoO>0.0</CoO>
            <CaO>12.45</CaO>
            <Na2O>2.65</Na2O>
            <K2O>0.03</K2O>
            <P2O5>0.08</P2O5>
            <H2O>0.20</H2O>
        </initialize>
        <calculationMode>equilibrate</calculationMode>
        <title>alpha testing</title>
        <constraints>
            <setTP>
                <initialT>1200</initialT>
                <initialP>1000</initialP>
            </setTP>
        </constraints>
    </MELTSinput>
```

Comment: `contentType` is the type of data you are *sending*.  As far as I know, HTTP POST does not allow anything other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I could be wrong about that.  Are you actually sending valid `text/xml` with `app._CONTENT`?

Comment: Apparently, since I can get a 200 response from the server with valid XML in return - but only in Chrome, not in Firefox.

Comment: Try removing the `contentType` parameter and see whether that works

Comment: We've tried that.  Without setting 'Content-Type', we get the 415 errors in Firefox AND Chrome.

Comment: What is `app._CONTENT`?

Comment: I edited to show what is sent in the body of the request.  It's valid XML.  I'll add that we've also tried sending Content-Type of xml and application/xml with the same results.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, but can you try `Content-Type: application/xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be character-set related as Miroshko suggests, but the most likely way to find the problem is to look on the server: watch the error logs there; there should be some explanation of the cause of the problem.  Perhaps the XML can't be parsed for some reason, so the server doesn't believe that it *is* XML.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with recognizing all possible XML type strings across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox adds charset automatically to Content-Type, so it becomes "text/xml; charset=utf-8". I guess, server just makes straight comparison thus gives 415